# Realtime Socket.IO scaling problem - python

Tags: python, real-time, socket.io, tornado

I'm trying to do something like the stream on *Facebook*, with socket.io 0.6 and tornadio.

Each user has is own comet channel/group in his wall.
I'm sending a comet message to the wall of all my friends (even if they aren't online).

The problem is about **scaling**: what if i have 1 million friends? It would take a long time to write in all walls.

Is there any solution more efficient to do this using comet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult problem in the social space. There is a trade-off between two approaches:

- **push**: When a user produces an event (e.g. a status update), you push that status update out to the stream of each of the user's friends. When a user loads his or her stream, you only have to read a record from a single place.
- **pull**: When a user produces an event, you write that even to the user's data record. When a user loads his stream, you poll the data record of each of his friends, aggregating the results on the fly.

The push method is good when loading a stream happens much more often than user updates and when the "fanout" of users (e.g. the maximum number of followers a user has) is low. The pull method is good when a user loading his stream is rare, or if the the number of users a user can follow is low.

I co-authored a [paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jterrace/docs/feeding-frenzy-sigmod10-web.pdf) on how to do this efficiently. Basically, we used a hybrid method, determining when to push or pull based on user statistics.

For simplicity, I would recommend you implement the pull model. Cache the results of the aggregation and only refresh a user's feed after the cache entry is stale for a certain period of time.

Comment: we have pull already developed for cases when a user enter the page for the first time. We need an eficient push for realtime updates (this way the user does not need to refresh the page).

Comment: are you only pushing to users that are currently logged in and active? if you only push to those users, are you still having scalability issues?

Comment: in fact that's not an option, because writing to all my friends would take a long time, and if i had to verify if my 1 million friends are logged and active it would take a lot long long time.

Comment: Why not keep a list of active user ids? Then if you load the 1 million friend user ids in memory, just take the intersection with the active set and only update those?